# I want to save a SharePoint page as a Word file?

Tags: 2010, word

I have a SP2010 page with numerous web parts. I want to put all this information onto a page that I can easily edit, add data, copy, print, etc. Is there any easy way to do this rather than copy paste, which produces undesirable results.

Any quick easy way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your aspx page to doc file programmatically, I have created a simple web part that contain just a hyperlink by clicking on it you current page will be downloaded as word document file.

Convert html to doc file

```
public void PrintPage(string pageHtmlContent)
{
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.Charset = "";
    Context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/msword.doc";
    Context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" +
                               "Document.doc");
    Context.Response.Write(pageHtmlContent);
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.End();
}
```

Retrieve html code of the current page, to do this the simplest way is to use javascript : `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Send the html as a string from the javascript to code behind,
To do this I use the :`__doPostBack` this function takes two arguments:

- EventTarget contains the ID of the control that causes the postback
- EventArgument contains any additional data associated with the control.

---

```
<a id="Boton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('Generate Document',document.documentElement.innerHTML)">
```

Add this code to the webpart `Page_Load`

```
Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);

// Test the Event Target 
if (Context.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "Generate Document")
{
    // Retrieve the site Url
    string currentSiteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;

    // Get the Event Argument 
    string eventArgument = Context.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");

    // Convert url form relative to absolute, 
    // otherwise they will not be included in the generated document
    string pageHtmlContent = eventArgument.Replace("href=\"", "href=\"" +
                             currentSiteUrl).Replace("src=\"", "src=\"" + 
                             currentSiteUrl);

    PrintPage(pageHtmlContent);
}
```

**The result :**

[image]

The generated document must be edited, because the [Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) is not supported.

[image]

The final result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Word, Click File -> Open, then in the file name address bar, paste the url of the web page you want to open in Word. That is all you can do. AFAIK, there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to you requirements, maybe a Wiki pages library is what you really need, or to be even more precise the Enterprise Wiki (if you the Enterprise License).

- The use of Page Layout would allow the best of both worlds - total control on placement of elements on the page (via Web-part zones placed wherever suits you)
- Usage of Publishing HTML field to allow for rich content editing.

These combined with some clever CSS and media queries (search the web for details, http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/), would allow you to define controls to include in the printing.

As for printing to Word, out-of-the-box, not really anything, but otherwise for the most controllable solution (development needed) is to consider Word Automation and submit the HTML content to create PDF/Word/XPS from it.